# Calculating TF-IDF Score of a Single String

Tags: python, scikit-learn, text-processing, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

I do a string matching using TF-IDF and Cosine Similarity and it's working good for finding the similarity between strings in a list of strings.

Now, I want to do the matching between a new string against the previously calculated matrix. I calculate the TF-IDF score using below code.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=1, analyzer=ngrams)
tf_idf_matrix = vectorizer.fit_transform(list_string)
```

How can I calculate the TF-IDF score of a new string against previous matrix? I can add the new string to the series and recalculate the matrix like below, but it will be inefficient since I only want the last index of the matrix and don't need the matrix of the old series to be recalculated.

```
list_string = list_string.append(new_string)

single_matrix = vectorizer.fit_transform(list_string)

single_matrix = single_matrix[len(list_string) - 1:]
```

After reading a while about TF-IDF calculation, I am thinking about saving the IDF value of each term and manually calculate the TF-IDF of the new string without using the matrix, but I don't know how to do that. How can I do this? Or is there any better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refitting the TF-IDF in order to calculate the score of a single entry is not the way; you should simply use the `.transform()` method of the existing fitted vectorizer to your new string (*not* to the whole matrix):

```
single_entry = vectorizer.transform(new_string)
```

See the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.transform).